# How can we link the phpmyadmin database with a proper domain?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Like suppose i have a domain named "abcd.com"

and in that  domain i have a phpmyadmin database installed.i have a main.php file too

how to initiate the connect from main.php file to a particular api function(which will update a value in the phpmyadmin database)?

Comment: Your db server should contain the necessary information about the url and port to the database. The rest depends entirely on you (creating a user to access the db and creating tables).

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of confusion.

You should understand that **PhpMyAdmin** is a "`webapp`" as much as the one that your writing `main.php`.
So, if you have the information about any PhpMyAdmin account, that one is the same as you DB's user.
You can use this information inside you main.php file to connect to the DB and "do stuff", as long as the main.php is in the same server that PhpMyAdmin.